# How to use parallel_scan to increase the efficiency to read out the file in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, parallels

I am using python and mongodb. I have a collection called citymap in mongodb and I need to read a field out from each document. Before, I did this:

```
for NN5_doc in citymap.find().batch_size(500):
    current_cell = citymap.find({'_id':NN5_doc['_id']})
    citycell_pool.append(current_cell[0]['big_cell8']['POI'])
```

Now I know that parallel_scan may help me to increase the efficiency to realize the same goal. However, I don't know how to do that. To the best of my knowledge, maybe I can use:

```
grid750_cursors = citymap.parallel_scan(5)
```

And then how do I handle these cursors and let them return me the same citycell_pool as I did before?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think `parallel_scan` is what you need here. Seems that your approach for the iteration isn't efficient. Why iterate through the citymap collection and then fetch from the same collection the same document you've already fetched? This would make more sense to me given your code:

```
for NN5_doc in citymap.find({},  {'big_cell8.POI': 1}).batch_size(500):
    citycell_pool.append(NN5_doc['big_cell8']['POI'])
```

Reading should be more efficient using projection (depending on the size of your documents) where you'd only be reading the fields you need (`big_cell8.POI`) and reduce the size of the retrieved documents. And by removing the redundant find from the loop, it should be at least twice as fast now.

Comment: thanks for your comments, I am sorry that I made a small typo in my question and I have corrected. I just want to fetch from EACH document in my collection, and according to your answer, where should the grid750_doc come from if I don't do citymap.find()

Comment: So it's event simpler now after your update, try my updated answer.